# How to fire OnActionExecuting in Web Api controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My api endpoints are using asp.net mvc (4) web api controllers.

Are there any events similiar to how mvc has OnActionExecuting?

Also, how to I access the Request object to lookup if the request has the authorization token?

Comment: `OnActionExecuting` is executed by default. I think you are looking for [AuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.onauthorization(v=vs.108).aspx)

Answer (score 35):

Since the filter Niko posted didn't work for me (I'm using the **`ApiController`** class), I implemented this filter:

```
public class MyActionFilter : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute 
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        // pre processing
    }
}
```

Make sure you *don't use* the ActionFilter from "System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute".

Comment: Thanks for complete namespace.. (in the world of ambiguous mvc-webapi names

Comment: how do you gain access to the request object from here? I need to grab something from the query string

Answer (score 12):

Use [action filters](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs).

```
public class MyActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
         //use filterContext.HttpContext.Request...
    }
}
```

For your controller action, apply the attribute

```
[MyActionFilter]
public Action MyAction(...)
{
    //...
}
```

---

As Satpal mentioned in his comment, you might actually want to use [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) to authorize access to your actions.

Comment: How does AuthorizeAttribute know what to do? i.e. I want to check that the current request has the correct token in the querystring.

Comment: AuthorizeAttribute works with membership providers in the asp.net mvc 4 websites, in a way that it can authorize users to access actions based on auth tokens in the request. [Details here](http://pluralsight.com/training/Player?author=scott-allen&name=mvc4-building-m7-security&mode=live&clip=0&course=mvc4-building). If you only need to check the querystring for some predetermined token, then it's easier to use the custom ActionFilter.

Comment: Can we use `ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)` or `Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)' method to override action call to validate if you don't want to use Authorze attribute?

Comment: ActionExecutingContext is for MVC , from web api you should use HttpActionContext