# How can I read and attribute from the controller/Action in Global.asax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, global-asax

In a WebApi 2 application, It's possible to read An attribute of the Action/Controller from the *Application_BeginRequest* method of the Global.Asax file?

Currently, I'm able to get the controller and action name, but don't know the best way to read a custom attribute from there.

Comment: I too want to read CustomAttribute on Action method inside global.asax in Application_OnPostAuthenticateRequest method? do you find any solution for this other than reflection?

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION 1**

Work with reflection.

**CAUTION** : this assumes that all your action names are unique for a controller.

If it's not true, I guess... this solution will fail miserably.

First, you need to find the assembly.

This can be done by choosing one of your api's controller, for example (they are of course few other ways to find the needed assembly)

```
var assembly = typeof (HomeController).Assembly;
```

Now, I guess you get the controller action and name this way :

```
var routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(
                new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));
var actionName = routeData.GetRequiredString("action");
var controllerName = routeData.GetRequiredString("controller");
```

So next step is to get the type of controller.
Which can be done either by

```
//you don't need the full name
var controllerType = assembly.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name ==  controllerName + "Controller");
```

or

```
var controllerType = assembly.GetType("<namespace>." + controllerName + "Controller");
```

Then you can get the controller's customAttributes

```
var controllerCustomAttributes = controllerType.GetCustomAttributes();
```

If you want the action attributes, you'll need to get the method corresponding to your action name.

```
var actionType = controllerType.GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == actionName );
```

then again, to get custom attributes

```
var actionAttributes = actionType.GetCustomAttributes();
```

**SOLUTION 2**

It may be better to add custom `ActionFilterAttribute` on all of your actions, and work with `OnActionExecuting`.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18919765/961526) for example.

Comment: Looks like the First Solution suits perfect to my use case. I can't use an ActionFilterAttribute because I need this code to be executed before the AuthorizationFilter (Hope don't be missing something in this point). Thanks ndeed Raphaël.